# Windows Forms C++-CLI: Replace dot with comma in textbox input

Tags: .net, winforms, input, textbox, c++-cli

I try to tackle very trivial part of problem with autocorrecting users' input to the textbox. I managed to detect whether or not user typed number (as necessary) and control its range. Now I need to autoreplace dots with commas any time user types it into textbox. I expected the following code snippet to work just fine:

```
private: System::Void sample_ctrl_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender,
        System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
    if (e->KeyCode == Keys::OemPeriod) {
        int pos = timer_period_ctrl->SelectionStart;
        sample_ctrl->Text = sample_ctrl->Text->Insert(pos,",");
        sample_ctrl->SelectionStart = pos + 1;
        e->Handled = true;  
    }
}
```

What I was expecting is to capture pressed key, handle it myself with *Insert()* and tell the listener that I did what had to be done with

```
e->Handled = true;
```

However, the outcome is as follows:

```
// Before hitting '.' key
    12

// After hitting '.' key
    12,.
```

Is there any way to ignore this natural '.' addition to the textbox? Is this the best possible way of tackling the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event rather than the `KeyDown` event.

This event uses [`KeyPressEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and so rather than

```
if (e->KeyCode == Keys::OemPeriod) {
```

you need to use

```
if (e->KeyChar == '.') {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm now :) Out of curiosity: I managed to handle event of hitting 'Enter' key with _KeyDown_ event to store my value as variable. Is there a sensible char equivalent for 'Enter' so I could manage both events with just one listener? It is not necessary, but it would be nicier solution as I would get rid of some unnecessary event listeners.

Comment: @irchris102 give me a minute.

Comment: @irchris102 The way it's done [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2) is to have two separate event handers (`KeyPress` and `KeyDown`) with a variable being set in `KeyDown` to tell if the character should be removed or not and the event being set as `Handled` if the variable is true in `KeyPress`. Through testing, I've discovered you can simply use `if (e->KeyChar == '\r') {`, however I don't know how portable this is.

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it would work properly. I checked how it would work on various OS'es. Here is a quote from another forum: 
_Different Operating Systems handle newlines in a different way. Here is a short list of the most common ones:_  
**DOS and Windows** They expect a newline to be the combination of two characters, namely '\r\n' (or 13 followed by 10).  **Unix (and hence Linux as well):** Unix uses a single '\n' to indicate a new line.  **Mac:** Macs use a single '\r'. The outcome is I will stay with additional listeners as it is now - 3 cases for this is just overkill. Thanks a lot!